# KeyDown event in a mdi childform

Tags: c#, keydown, mdichild, mdiparent

I'm using a mdi parent form and a mdi child form. When I press a key I would like something in the child form to change, but it looks like if I press a key it's the parent form that register the keydown event. Is there anyway to make the child form register the keydown event or make the parent form send the information of the keydown event to the child form?

Comment: Either can have a handler for the event.  Register the event in the child, not the parent, if that's where you want it.

Comment: How do I do that, I'm pretty new to coding... Because when I press the key that I use a keydown event for, it only get registered in the parent form. and I would like to change something with a keydown event in the child form